# WiFi keeps disconnecting and asking for password

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, internet

It's happening on my work's PC and it's making me mad. Just wanted to start from zero this new year with Linux.

WiFi runs good for X time; may be 5 minutes or 10 hours. But at a point, it disconnects and I have to restart NetworkManager until it works again (sometimes one time, sometimes 50).

I have a TP-Link TL wn722n v1

Here goes the dmesg information when I can't connect:

```
[ 3052.682234] wlp0s2f1u3: disassociated from 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
[ 3055.251532] wlp0s2f1u3: authenticate with 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c
[ 3055.251560] wlp0s2f1u3: 80 MHz not supported, disabling VHT
[ 3055.380416] wlp0s2f1u3: send auth to 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c (try 1/3)
[ 3055.383389] wlp0s2f1u3: authenticated
[ 3055.385228] wlp0s2f1u3: associate with 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c (try 1/3)
[ 3055.391383] wlp0s2f1u3: RX AssocResp from 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=1)
[ 3055.398247] wlp0s2f1u3: associated
[ 3055.398367] wlp0s2f1u3: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c
[ 3059.511610] wlp0s2f1u3: disassociated from 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
[ 3059.782424] wlp0s2f1u3: authenticate with 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c
[ 3059.782449] wlp0s2f1u3: 80 MHz not supported, disabling VHT
[ 3059.911801] wlp0s2f1u3: send auth to 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c (try 1/3)
[ 3059.914739] wlp0s2f1u3: authenticated
[ 3059.915667] wlp0s2f1u3: associate with 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c (try 1/3)
[ 3059.921250] wlp0s2f1u3: RX AssocResp from 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=1)
[ 3059.927504] wlp0s2f1u3: associated
[ 3060.001159] wlp0s2f1u3: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c
[ 3064.044143] wlp0s2f1u3: disassociated from 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
[ 3066.363036] wlp0s2f1u3: authenticate with 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c
[ 3066.363083] wlp0s2f1u3: 80 MHz not supported, disabling VHT
[ 3066.492921] wlp0s2f1u3: send auth to 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c (try 1/3)
[ 3066.495447] wlp0s2f1u3: authenticated
[ 3066.496732] wlp0s2f1u3: associate with 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c (try 1/3)
[ 3066.505890] wlp0s2f1u3: RX AssocResp from 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=1)
[ 3066.511998] wlp0s2f1u3: associated
[ 3066.554904] wlp0s2f1u3: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c
[ 3070.621502] wlp0s2f1u3: disassociated from 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
[ 3072.710773] wlp0s2f1u3: authenticate with 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c
[ 3072.710822] wlp0s2f1u3: 80 MHz not supported, disabling VHT
[ 3072.846055] wlp0s2f1u3: send auth to 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c (try 1/3)
[ 3072.850733] wlp0s2f1u3: authenticated
[ 3072.851837] wlp0s2f1u3: associate with 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c (try 1/3)
[ 3072.860616] wlp0s2f1u3: RX AssocResp from 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=1)
[ 3072.866786] wlp0s2f1u3: associated
[ 3072.904667] wlp0s2f1u3: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c
[ 3076.981498] wlp0s2f1u3: disassociated from 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
[ 3078.834040] wlp0s2f1u3: authenticate with 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c
[ 3078.834087] wlp0s2f1u3: 80 MHz not supported, disabling VHT
[ 3078.963799] wlp0s2f1u3: send auth to 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c (try 1/3)
[ 3078.966331] wlp0s2f1u3: authenticated
[ 3078.969241] wlp0s2f1u3: associate with 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c (try 1/3)
[ 3078.974849] wlp0s2f1u3: RX AssocResp from 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=1)
[ 3078.981019] wlp0s2f1u3: associated
[ 3079.047912] wlp0s2f1u3: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c
[ 3083.101447] wlp0s2f1u3: disassociated from 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
```

... and it keeps going and going.
This time, I disconected and reconnected the WiFi adapter and it worked properly on the first try.
dmesg said:

```
usb 2-3: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 3104.603330] ath: phy1: Failed to wakeup in 500us
[ 3104.613501] ath: phy1: Failed to wakeup in 500us
[ 3104.625429] usb 2-3: ath9k_htc: USB layer deinitialized
[ 3105.038275] usb 2-3: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[ 3108.388314] usb 2-3: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[ 3108.537180] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=9271, bcdDevice= 1.08
[ 3108.537200] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=16, Product=32, SerialNumber=48
[ 3108.537208] usb 2-3: Product: USB2.0 WLAN
[ 3108.537244] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: ATHEROS
[ 3108.537250] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: 12345
[ 3108.538030] usb 2-3: ath9k_htc: Firmware ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw requested
[ 3108.835993] usb 2-3: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw, size: 51008
[ 3109.086934] ath9k_htc 2-3:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits
[ 3109.317934] ath9k_htc 2-3:1.0: ath9k_htc: FW Version: 1.4
[ 3109.317950] ath9k_htc 2-3:1.0: FW RMW support: On
[ 3109.317956] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x809c
[ 3109.317961] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[ 3109.317964] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[ 3109.317967] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x52
[ 3109.317971] ath: Country alpha2 being used: CN
[ 3109.317975] ath: Regpair used: 0x52
[ 3109.325025] ieee80211 phy2: Atheros AR9271 Rev:1
[ 3109.347720] ath9k_htc 2-3:1.0 wlp0s2f1u3: renamed from wlan0
[ 3121.003081] wlp0s2f1u3: authenticate with 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c
[ 3121.003128] wlp0s2f1u3: 80 MHz not supported, disabling VHT
[ 3121.131517] wlp0s2f1u3: send auth to 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c (try 1/3)
[ 3121.136660] wlp0s2f1u3: authenticated
[ 3121.138327] wlp0s2f1u3: associate with 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c (try 1/3)
[ 3121.149173] wlp0s2f1u3: RX AssocResp from 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=1)
[ 3121.155326] wlp0s2f1u3: associated
[ 3121.237579] wlp0s2f1u3: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by 08:4f:0a:4b:cd:4c
```

I'm waiting for it to fail again. If anyone can give me a hand I'll be grateful!
Thank you all.